# Flutter POST request problems

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I am new in Flutter and I am trying to make a POST request and get an authorization token from an api method called userRequestCode(). I tried to paste code inside /////// but it doesn't work. If I paste this code inside userRequestCode(), how can I catch exceptions? Help me, please.

```
Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
Map<String, String> headersWithAuthorization = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'bearer ${getMobileToken()}'};

Future<String> getMobileToken() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
  return prefs.getString(_token) ?? '';
}

Future<bool> setMobileToken(String token) async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
  return prefs.setString(_token, token);
}

Future<http.Response> userRequestCode(String body) async {
  final response = await http.post(baseUrl + " ", body: body, headers: headers);
  return response;
}

Future<http.Response> userLogin(String body) async {
  final response = await http.post(baseUrl + " ", body: body, headers: headersWithAuthorization);
  return response;
}

class CodeResponse {
  final String token;

  CodeResponse({this.token});

  factory CodeResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CodeResponse(
      token: json['token'],
    );
  }
}

void _confirmPressed() {
  var body = jsonEncode({
    "appId": appId,
    "phone": widget.phone.replaceAll("(", "").replaceAll(")", "").replaceAll("-", ""),
    "code": "1234",
  });

  var data = json.encode(body);
  print(data);

  userConfirmCode(body).then((response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      //        _codeResponse = CodeResponse.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      //        _token = _codeResponse.token;
      //        print(_token);
      //        setMobileToken(_token);
      print(response.body);
      print(response.statusCode);
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Profile(oldPassword: widget.password)));
    } else if (response.statusCode == 403) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text("Wrong Code"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ));
      print(response.statusCode);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }).catchError((error) {
    print('error : $error');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with `headersWithAuthorization`:

1) It is initialized once and will not update if token in prefs change;

2) `${getMobileToken()}` works like `getMobileToken().toString()` which doesn't await actual string value but gives you `Future`'s string representation instead. Try printing it to see what this representation looks like.

To fix this, replace `headersWithAuthorization` variable with async function:

```dart
Future<Map<String, String>> getHeadersWithAuthorization() async {
  final String mobileToken = await getMobileToken();
  return {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'bearer $mobileToken'};
}
```

Then, when you need headers with authorization, call this function and await its value:

```dart
Future<http.Response> userLogin(String body) async {
  final headersWithAuth = await getHeadersWithAuthorization();
  final response = await http.post(baseUrl + " ", body: body, headers: headersWithAuth);
  return response;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, can you help to get this token? what do i do wrong?

Comment: I don't know what the server returns when you query the token. Try printing `response.body`